# Cannot Write to sdcard in Android emulator

Tags: android, permissions, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I have added this line in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, when I run code to write to the sdcard , I get this Error:

```
02-19 13:24:46.760: E/CameraTest(598): /mnt/sdcard/image.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

How do I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I am using the Android Emulator with SDCard added.

**EDIT-2:** I know what the problem is now: I have called the function `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` and I get "removed". Anyone knows how to fix this and make the state `MEDIA_MOUNTED`

Thank You!

Comment: check [this][1] and [this][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/android-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334090/failed-to-save-image-to-sdcard

Comment: @thinksteep : yes the sd card is added. I am using the emulator by the way.

Comment: @thinksteep : apparently when I print out the getExternalStorageState I get "removed" so how to I mount the SD card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok So I have solved this. It was a problem I faced with mounting the sdcard and that android doesn't allow spaces in the path!

Here is a good procedure to follow (if eclipse is also used) : http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/33240.aspx

NOTE: in case the path has a space in it, move the sdcard image file to somewhere else and then run the emulator command with the sdcard and everything should work fine!

Answer (score 3):

It might be more simple than that. I missed to configure the emulator so that it had a SD-card. Once I added a SD-card in the device, everything went well.

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 2):

I notice that this problem can occur if you are using an Android 6.0 emulator, Android added new permission model for (Marshmallow).

**Trick**: If you are targeting version 22 or below, your application will request all permissions at install time just as it would on any device running an OS below Marshmallow

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the cache for whichever application I was using to try and share out the picture (Pixlr) and it was fine.