# Android : open failed eacces permission denied

Tags: android

i am new to android. i have tried this code

in manifest file i wrote this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in java code

```
   File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"store.txt");
```

but i am getting above exception

i want to perform file read and write operations and i am using version 4.4.2.

i am getting this error

```
06-14 02:19:44.491: D/Shopping Cart(1700): open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: 06-14 02:13:02.061: D/Shopping Cart(1637): open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: please post full logcat error and add to your question.

Comment: The code you showed does not provoke that error. Please add the statement that does.

Comment: i have same problem on Galaxy S4. How did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your permission is right place in `manifest` file as

```
    <application>
        ...

    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    </manifest>
```

**Edit**

Try to edit the Emulator

1. go to android virtual device manager and then edit the emulator
2. set say 100 MB for Sd card for the respected emulator and say Ok
3. save and close emulator and start
4. path saved in DDMS is **mnt/sdcard/yourfilename**

it worked for me the app is not giving Error and is working

Please see more at this link [Cannot Write to sdcard in Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351904/cannot-write-to-sdcard-in-android-emulator)
 and this link [Guide to Emulating an SD Card Using the Google Android Emulator](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/33240.aspx)

Comment: @user3201607 Are you testing in emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Under kitkat your app can only write to an app specific directory on the -removable- sd card. You get possible directories using getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: It works with Android 4.4 on a Nexus 7 but it does not on a Galaxy S4, I'm getting crazy with this problem.