# How to read file form sd card Android 4.4 Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sdcard, readfile

I am creating an app in which I would like to read a file from the sd card and then write to another file using info from the other file. When attempting to read the file I get the following error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'sdcard/android/data/App1.App1/files/' is denied.

Read Function:

```
private string ReadFile(string fileName)
{
      var path = "sdcard/android/data/App1.App1/files/";
      var filePath = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), fileName);
      string text = File.ReadAllText(path.ToString());
      return text;
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App1.App1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="Scout" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check this tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/StorageClient/
 But this is for only storing in the internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue and found that I was trying to read a folder instead of the file itself. When switching out the variable path with filePath int the read all text function the error went away.

Answer (score -1):

Do not forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

into the manifest. This allows to read and write on SD card.

More details about [uses-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

It can also be a problem with your simulator and your sd card, read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351904/cannot-write-to-sdcard-in-android-emulator)

Comment: I have already done this and I have the ability to write to the sd card but am still unable to read, even from my apps designated directory. As for using a simulator, I am debugging the app from my own phone.

Comment: Permissions are not really concern in XAMARIN. By default the platform will takecare.

Comment: Here the issue, 
 Using XAMARIN Cross Platform development tool.. It is very hard to read & write the file/folders from the SD Card.