# Send PDF File from php server to android

Tags: php, android

I have created a pdf document on a PHP server and I would like to send the file to an android device, and then have the android view the file. Can anyone help me with the code in PHP and android? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334090/failed-to-save-image-to-sdcard/9334437#9334437)

change

```
String url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
```

to

```
String url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/yourfile.pdf";
```

and please also change

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Path+"some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");//obj
```

to

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Path+"yourfilename.pdf");//obj
```

it works thanks